# Using regex and pandas in the DataFrame to replace the value

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

```
import pandas as pd
import re

regexdf_data = {
    'STag': ['Title_1', 'Abs_1', 'Abs_3', 'Abs_4'],
    'E1': ['pacnes', 'acne|dfe|sac', 'pI', 'kera'],
    'E1_CUI': ['C3477', 'C2166', 'C9871', 'C2567']
}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(regexdf_data)
df3

    E1             E1_CUI    STag
0   pacnes         C3477     Title_1
1   acne|dfe|sac   C2166     Abs_1
2   pI             C9871     Abs_3
3   kera           C2567     Abs_4
```

Now I want only acne from acne|dfe|sac value of E1 column in place of C2166 of E1_CUI column when there is Abs_1 value in STag column of the corresponding row.

I have tried this `df3.loc[df3['STag'] == 'Abs_1', 'E1_CUI'] = re.split("\|",df3['E1'])` but its not working.

```
Expected Output

    E1             E1_CUI    STag
0   pacnes         C3477     Title_1
1   acne|dfe|sac   acne      Abs_1
2   pI             C9871     Abs_3
3   kera           C2567     Abs_4
```

Comment: How do you determine it should be `acne`? is it a match on a specific word or simply the first split on `|`?

Comment: @ALollz  Yes, It should be taken as simply the first split on |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using string accessor with split and the get shortcut for first element (improvements by @ShubhamSharma):

```
import pandas as pd

regexdf_data = {
    'STag': ['Title_1', 'Abs_1', 'Abs_3', 'Abs_4'],
    'E1': ['pacnes', 'acne|dfe|sac', 'pI', 'kera'],
    'E1_CUI': ['C3477', 'C2166', 'C9871', 'C2567']
}

df3 = pd.DataFrame(regexdf_data)

m = df3['STag'] == 'Abs_1'
df3.loc[m, 'E1_CUI'] = df3.loc[m, 'E1'].str.split('|').str[0]
```

Output:

```
print(df3)

      STag            E1 E1_CUI
0  Title_1        pacnes  C3477
1    Abs_1  acne|dfe|sac   acne
2    Abs_3            pI  C9871
3    Abs_4          kera  C2567
```

Comment: Hi Scott! Nice answer just a small optimization tip may be we can use boolean masking to slice only the interested portion of column `E1` to avoid splitting the entire column :)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Yes, you are correct.  Please feel free to edit the solution and document with your name.  Excellent idea!

Comment: Edited the answer!